# $2^{\omega_1}$ separable?

Tags: gn.general-topology

I was rereading an answer to an old question of mine and it included a reference to the fact that $2^{\omega_1}$ was separable. I'm having a hard time finding a reference for this fact, and the proof is not immediately obvious to me. Can anyone provide me with a cite and/or a proof?

Comment: Related question on MSE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97413/on-the-product-of-separable-spaces

Answer (score 4):

Should have searched a bit harder before asking this one. This is an immediate consequence of the Hewitt-Marczewski-Pondiczery theorem:

Let $m \geq \aleph_0$. If $\{X_s : s \in S\}$ are topological spaces with $d(X_s) \leq m$ and $|S| \leq 2^m$ then $d(\prod_s X_s) \leq m$.

Comment: That's overkill, I think. $2^{[0;1]}$ separable is much easier to prove than the Hewitt-Marczewski-Pondiczery Theorem. In fact, the countable system of Walsh functions is dense in $\{-1;1\}^{[0,1)}$  ... mathworld.wolfram.com/WalshFunction.html

Comment: Of course one also needs $\aleph_1 \le 2^{\aleph_0}$ for this simple proof to work, which is non-constructive (requires Axiom of Choice).  Can one prove without choice that $2^{\omega_1}$ is separable?

Comment: @Gerald: Good question! The statement appears to imply `$\aleph_1 \leq 2^{\aleph_0}$`. If `$\{d_n\}_{n<\omega}$` enumerates a dense subset then the sets `$D_\alpha = \{n<\omega: d_n(\alpha) = 1\}$` must be distinct since `$D_\alpha\setminus D_\beta$` cannot be empty when $\alpha \neq \beta$.

Comment: Is it not the case that $\aleph_1 \leq 2^{\aleph_0}$ without the axiom of the choice? I think the following should work: By constructing with transfinite induction we can find $g_\alpha : [0, \alpha) \to \mathbb{Q}$ an injection (using the standard argument that countable ordinals embed in the rationals), and so $f_\alpha : \alpha \to \omega$ a bijection. We now define `$f : \omega_1 \to  \{0, 1\}^\omega$ inductively as a diagonalisation of $f(\beta)$ for $\beta < \alpha$, which we can do without AC because we can explicitly count $\alpha$

Comment: You can't necessarily "define `$f : \omega_1 \to \{0, 1\}^\omega$ inductively as a diagonalisation of $f(\beta)$ for $\beta < \alpha$" without AC because even though you can explicitly count $\alpha$, $\alpha$ isn't explicitly counted.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar It would be interesting if one could prove the converse, that separability of $2^{\omega_1}$ implies $\aleph_1\le2^{\aleph_0}$. I don't see how to do that, but it seems to me that separability of $2^{\omega_1}$ does imply the weaker inequality $2^{\aleph_1}\le2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$. Have I got that right? That **is** weaker, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed the Hewitt-Marczewski-Pondiczery theorem. My proof, following Engelking, is [here](http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist_2010;task=show_msg;msg=0487.0001). It's in fact not that hard, the fact for a product of copies of 2 point discrete spaces already implies the general theorem pretty quickly.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for the tip, I fixed the link.

Comment: The link seems to be down (or moved?), I'll add at least here in the comment a [Wayback Machine link](http://web.archive.org/web/2015*/http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist_2010;task=show_msg;msg=0487.0001).